# Have names on the spheres built by rgl package plot3d

Tags: r, plot, rgl

Is there a way to have the names shown when use plot3d(rgl) in R to build a 3d graph, cause it's hard to locate which entry the sphere belongs to when I have many spheres to plot on the same coordinate. For example, I have the data:

```
    x   y   z
A   0.1 -0.5    3.2
B   -1.1    1.2 0.8
C   2.0 2.1 0.6
......

plot3d(data,type="s",radius=0.025)
```

But, I want to have the name A, B, C shown on the graph as it's easier to observe.
Or to have the name shown only when I put the mouse onto one specific sphere.
I have tried to use different colors, but when I have like 20 spheres, it seems it will run out of colors or colors are too close to distinguish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function `text3d()` in library `rgl` that can be used to plot texts inside plot. This example shows how to plot row names as texts.

```
plot3d(data,type="s",radius=0.025)
text3d(data$x,data$y,data$z,text=rownames(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine the use of `text3d` with `identify3d()` to identify points you want to label interactively with your mouse

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example? It does not work for me, the plot is just empty :(

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out myself. First, you have to open a 3D plot and then, before you close it, make a call to identify3d(), which should get the same data.