# How to pick an element using mouse in RGL plot3d?

Tags: r, rgl

I calculate principal components of my multivariate dataset and display scores of first 3 principal components as spheres on a 3-dimensional interactive plot with `rgl::plot3d`. Unfortunately, it is not always clear which sphere on the 3D plot corresponds to which observation in my dataset. **Is there some simple way to add a mouse callback that would return the index of the clicked sphere?**

```
# For example, I plot iris
library(rgl)
with(iris, plot3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                      type="s", col=as.numeric(Species)))

# Now I click on some data points and want to get their indices
# how?
```

I have checked [WebGL user interaction tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html#controls), but it doesn't mention such functionality. I also figured out that with a fancy combination of `translationMatrix` and `rgl.setMouseCallbacks` one can get location of the mouse pointer in the plot coordinates, and then potentially link to the nearest element, but it seems to be crazy complicated.

Comment: You can have a look at plotly: https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. Capabilities of plotly look really impressive, I'll try it out.

Comment: plot.ly 3d does not have any where near the flexibilite of rgl as far as I can tell. Unfortunately. It doesn't even have a way to do line segments.

Answer (score 1):

All right, in the question [Have names on the spheres built by rgl package plot3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366028) I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813180/6029703) than mentions function `rgl::identify3d`. It does exactly what I am looking for. Here is a minimal working example:

```
library(rgl)
attach(iris)
plot3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
       type="s", col=as.numeric(Species))
pts <- identify3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length,
       labels = rownames(iris))
# Use the right button to select, the middle button to quit

pts
# [1] 120 107  42  14   2 106 118
detach(iris)

iris[pts, ]  # get selected observations
```